# Need to show positive bills and negative bills

Tags: python

Some of the vars are in Portuguese sorry. I am trying to show how much of which type of money bills you will and will not get on a atm:

example:

```
IN: $123,45

OUT:1 OF $100 BILL, 0 OF $50 BILL, 1 OF $20 BILL, 0 OF $10 BILL and etc.
```

This is what I did so far but I can't do the bill that will not come on the atm.

```
r = 0
print('='*20)
print('{:^20}'.format('CAIXA ELETRÔNICO'))
print('{:^20}'.format(' Banco do Romeu '))
print('='*20)

caixa = float(input('Qual será o valor sacado? '))
total = caixa
ced = 100
totalced = 0

while True:

    if total >= ced:
        total = total - ced
        totalced += 1

    else:
        if totalced > 0:
            print(f'{totalced} notas(s) de R${ced}')

        elif ced == 100:
            ced = 50
        elif ced == 50:
            ced = 20
        elif ced == 20:
            ced = 10
        elif ced == 10:
            ced = 5
        elif ced == 5:
            ced = 2
        elif ced == 2:
            ced = 1
        elif ced == 1:
            ced = 0.50
        elif ced == 0.50:
            ced = 0.25
        elif ced == 0.25:
            ced = 0.10
        elif ced == 0.10:
            ced = 0.05
        elif ced == 0.05:
            ced = 0.01
        totalced = 0

        if total == 0:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a greedy approach and try to subtract the highest value bill and keep a count of how many times you subtracted from each bill. For example:

423,45

You start with $100, you can subtract it 4 times. You're left with 23,45.
Then you go on to $50. You can't subtract $50 from 23,45 so you go to the next highest bill, $20.
You can subtract one $20 from 23,45 and you're left with ,45.

You keep on going and keep count until you can't subtract anymore. Then you print out the count of subtractions from each bill. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract value from initial value.
variable valor is the initial value

```
valor = 162
cells = []
money = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2]

for _ in money:

    while True:

        if valor >= _:        
            if valor - _ < money[-1] or (valor % _) % money[-1] != 0:
                if valor == _:
                    cells.append(_)
                break
            valor -= _
            cells.append(_)

        else:
            break

print(cells)

>>> [100, 50, 10, 2]
```